# Best way to find script in solr documents

Tags: solr, lucene, similarity, proximity

What'd be the best way to search for a script in some loose way in SOLR

for example

```
q:"this is some script I'm looking"
```

possible retrieved docs:

```
"...this is some script...."
"...script you are looking"
"...this is our script..."
```

In short

1. not all terms may appear but more terms-> higher doc score
2. some proximity allowed

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic Solr capabilities and would be introduced in almost any tutorial in the subject. Use the [edismax query parser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax), and for the first question, use [mm parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29), while the second will be solved by default - or if you want, use [phrase fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29) or, depending on your need, the other phrase parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I wasn't able to prove myself the whole functionality I'd like is working..tried {!edismax pf3=Text ps3=10}(term1~ term2~ term3~ term4~)~50 for example, some of the results were too loose etc.. not sure SOLR is my answer here